# Unable to recover code from vs code after discarding changes in GitHub software

Tags: visual-studio, github, vscode-remote, github-for-windows

My vs code is integrated with GitHub software for windows 10, i write code then in GitHub software i accidentally discarded changes, and my all written code for the day is removed from vs code after discarding from the GitHub software.how can i recover the code please help

I tried every possible things from my end, now I want to reach someone on stack overflow who can help

Comment: If you discarded uncommitted changes then there's unlikely much that you can do. I've had days like this when you're not paying as much attention to what you're doing as you should. The only thing you can do is take it on the chin and redo what you've already done.